# Make either text-INPUT fields or SELECT OPTION required (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/kfqbbn3k/

There are two divs:

div **#1**:

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div>Firstname</div>
    <div class='resetOptions'>
        <input id='vVorname' name='uVorname' type='text' size='21'></input>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;" />
    <div>Lastname</div>
        <div class='resetOptions'>
            <input id='vNachname' name='uNachname' type='text' size='21'></input>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

div **#2**:

```
<div class="wrapUser">  <a href="#" class="show_hide">b) Registered Customer</a>

        <div class="slidingDiv">

            <div>
                <select>";
                    <option selected='true' value='' id='navOrderAddOrderChoose'>Choose</option>
                    <option value='CustomerA'>CustomerA</option>
                    <option value='CustomerB'>CustomerB</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The **1st div** is used if the *customer isn't registered* in the Database yet.

The **2nd div** is used if the *customer is already in the databas*e (I removed the PHP Code for this example).

**What I want to do**: I want to add a HTML5 REQUIRED control to these fields. If either the text-INPUT-fields (div1) are filled OR an SELECT OPTION (div2) is selected, the form can submit. If no div is filled out the form can't pass. So:

REQUIRED is either information from DIV1 or from DIV2.

(Please check the fiddle Code for further information)

Comment: Is no one able to answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Why not initially  mark both text fields `required` then on change event of drop-down either set or remove `required` attribute for text fields based on the selection made.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfqbbn3k/2/)

(points to note: in the markup I've removed `novalidate` on the input text fields and replaced it with `required`. Also I've commented the slidingDiv implementation.

Comment: Thank you, this helps! Is there any workarround for the _display-none_ issue?

Comment: @user3444297 there is no issue with display:none (try uncommenting the script and css). Say you try to submit with 'choose' option, still you won't be able to submit but since the new customer div is collapsed your validation messages for the text box are hidden. You should come up with a better flow for the user interface design.